# AFNetworking 2.0 - Forced caching

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

Is it possible to force response caching if it contains neither `Expires` or `Cache-Control: max-age`?

I've came across [this](http://www.hpique.com/2014/03/how-to-cache-server-responses-in-ios-apps/) article, but unfortunately `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:`  never gets called in my `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [`cachePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/cachePolicy) property of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the caching by implementing your own `NSURLProtocol` that does not follow the standard HTTP caching rules. A [complete tutorial is here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial), which persists the data using Core Data, but the basic steps are:

- Subclass `NSURLProtocol`
- Register your subclass with `+registerClass:`
- Return `YES` in your `+canInitWithRequest:` method if this is the first time you've seen `request`, or `NO` if it isn't

You now have two choices:

1. Implement your own cache storage (in which case, follow the tutorial linked above)
2. Inject the cache control headers that you wish the URL loading system to follow

Assuming you want #2, override `connection:didReceiveResponse:` in your protocol subclass to create a response that has the cache control headers you want to emulate:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {
    // Create a dictionary with the headers you want
    NSMutableDictionary *newHeaders = [response.allHeaderFields mutableCopy];
    newHeaders[@"Cache-Control"] = @"no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900";

    // Create a new response
    NSHTTPURLResponse *newResponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:response.URL
                                                                 statusCode:response.statusCode
                                                                HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1"
                                                               headerFields:newHeaders];


    [self.client URLProtocol:self
          didReceiveResponse:newResponse
          cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
}
```

This will cause the response to be cached as if the server had provided these headers.

---

**For URL sessions only**, you need to set the session configuration's `protocolClasses`. Since you're using AFNetworking, that looks like:

```
[AFHTTPSessionManager sharedManager].session.configuration.protocolClasses = @[[MyURLProtocol class]]
```

There are some caveats, so make sure you [read the `protocolClasses` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/protocolClasses).

---

A few notes:

- If there's any way to fix this by having your server send the appropriate headers, please, please do that instead.
- For the sake of brevity I hardcoded "HTTP/1.1", but technically you should pull this out of the response.
- AFNetworking uses the standard URL Loading System, and is mostly unrelated to this issue.

Comment: thanks so much! just got back to town, will dig into this tomorrow and then award you the bounty.

Comment: @BenW Cool, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: got this all set up, but for some reason startLoading is never called on my NSURLProtocol subclass even when i return YES from canInitWithRequest. both methods will be called when loading images, but startLoading isn't called when loading requests to my api. ever seen that?

Comment: i should mention i'm registering it first thing in didFinishLoadingWithOptions so it should have priority and i can't find any other url protocols that are registered.

Comment: @BenW Is `canInitWithRequest:` called? If yes, and you're returning `YES` from that, `startLoading` should be called. If no, did you register the subclass using `registerClass:` before making any requests?

Comment: @BenW Also, did you implement `canonicalRequestForRequest:`, `requestIsCacheEquivalent:toRequest:`, and `stopLoading` as well? Those are also required methods.

Comment: @BenW Also, I just realized you're using URL sessions. You may need to `return YES` from `canInitWithTask:` if you're using `NSURLSessionTask`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62212/discussion-between-ben-w-and-aaron-brager).

Comment: The linked article is fantastic, and so is this answer, thank you!